EF Core ignore column when requesting a list, but include when getting by Id
I have a list of invoices, which have generated files which are stored in the database.
I want to avoid loading the file data itself when retrieving a list of the invoices, but load it when the user clicks the download button for it.
Is there a way to achieve this? I saw the ignore for fluent configuration but it ignores it all the time.
Example code:
Class:
public class InvoiceFile
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public string FileName { get; set; }
    public byte[] File { get; set; }

    public Guid InvoiceId { get; set; }
    public Invoice Invoice { get; set; }
}

I want the File property to be ignored in the first query,  but loaded in the second:
var invoices = await _payoutDbContext.Invoices
    .Include(x => x.InvoiceFiles)
    .AsNoTracking()
    .AsSplitQuery()
    .ToListAsync();

var file - await _payoutDbContext.InvoiceFiles
    .Where(x => x.Id == invoiceId)
    .AsNoTracking()
    .FirstOrDefaultAsync();


Fairly confident this falls under https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/issues/1387, and therefore just not possible right now. Your only option is to use projections in the case you don't want to include it, store the filename in a seperate table, or something really hacky like using two entity classes for the same table that reference each other.

You could use a Raw SQL to perform the Query : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/ef6/querying/raw-sql

You cannot control what to load and what do not without Select, full entity is loaded by default. But you can configure your entity using Table splitting
With Select it is easy and preferrable, but I recommend to use special DTO classses for that:
var invoices = await _payoutDbContext.Invoices
    .Select(x => new InvoiceDto
    {
        Id = x.Id
        // ... other properties

        InvoiceFiles = x.InvoiceFiles.Select(f => new InvoiceFileDto
        {
            Id = f.Id,
            FileName = f.FileName
        }).ToList()
    })
    .AsSplitQuery()
    .ToListAsync();


I ended up using the projection approach, even though I personally prefer to let EF handle as much as possible of the work. I like the table splitting approach, though, just couldn't implement it due to time constraints, definitely worth a refactor task down the line.

Actually it is bad idea to send model via API. Projecting to DTO is preferrable solution when you can control what to send and what not. Also it reduces amount of transferred data, not always you need all field.

Since you don't need tracking you can just write custom Select for the first case:
var invoices = await _payoutDbContext.Invoices
    .AsSplitQuery()
    .Select(i => new Invoice
    {
        // ... - select all other proprerties
        InvoiceFiles = i.InvoiceFiles
            .Select(iFile => new InvoiceFile
            {
                Id = iFile.Id,
                FileName= iFile.FileName
            })
            .ToList()
    })
    .ToListAsync();

Personally I would recommend to create set of specific DTO for this case.
Also see table splitting if you still want to try solving this on the EF Core entity model level.
